# matlab expression Equivalent in R

Tags: r, matlab

Which expression would be the most similar to the following one:

```
BDe(i,:) = [];
```

I use this to delete the row i of BDe (matrix n*m dimension) in a for loop.

A reproducible example:

```
data = [ 1 1 1 ; 2 2 2; 3 3 3]
data =
 1     1     1
 2     2     2
 3     3     3
data(1,:)=[]
data =
 2     2     2
 3     3     3
```

## Target

Drop observations by iterating their matrix number row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure you are looking for for

**Example Data**

```
data=read.table(text=" 1     1     1
 2     2     2
                3     3     3")
```

**Code**

```
 data[-1,]

  V1 V2 V3
2  2  2  2
3  3  3  3
```

Note please be aware of the following behavior in a loop.

```
x<-1:10
for(i in c(2,3,7)){x<-x[-i]}
x
[1]  1  3  5  6  7  8 10
```

It can be better to just do

```
x<-1:10
x[-c(2,3,7)]
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would recommend, that you use a some kind of filter function instead of "deleting" 1 row. For example, it would look like this, if you want to keep only the rows, which have a sum of 6:

```
filter <- function(x) {
  sum(x) == 6
}

BDe[apply(BDe, 1, filter), ]
```

If you want to delete a row, you can't assign an empty vector for a row, what you can do is to reassign your the matrix without the ith row:

```
BDe <- BDe[-i,]
```